# How to pass value of item_name to Paypal page?

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

I have a webpage with products that requires paypal to be purchased.
I have used a selectbox for various options available for that product.

Although I have integrated paypal successfully and the html page is passing "amount" to paypal page.
What i am not able to do is passing the "item_name" corresponding to the selected option to paypal page.

Any help is much appreciated,Thanks in advance.

```
    <form name="" action="shop_paypal.php" method="post">
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
        <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="UK" />
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
        <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
       <div class="price-bottom-box">
       <!--<input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name"value="20,000 PINS" hidden="true"/>-->
        <select name="amount" id="amount" style="width:256px; height:32px;">
            <option value="18" id="1">10,000 PINS - $18 </option>
            <option value="35" id="2">20,000 PINS - $35</option>
            <option value="75" id="3">30,000 PINS - $75</option>
            <option value="140" id="4">50,000 PINS - $140</option>
            </select>
    <input type = "image" value = "submtbtn" name = "submtbtn"  src="images/buy-now-normal-bg.jpg" id="Image1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: I think it would be unethical not make sure you understand something first: it is very possible to send 'shop_paypal.php' **ANY AMOUNT** value. PLEASE DO NOT trust the value sent as 'amount'. You should uses the value passed as item_name (or even better item_id) and look up the value that corresponds to the requested item.

Now how to do it the seemingly *UNSECURE* way:

Replace your code:

```
<!--<input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name"value="20,000 PINS" hidden="true"/>-->
<select name="amount" id="amount" style="width:256px; height:32px;">
     <option value="18" id="1">10,000 PINS - $18 </option>
     <option value="35" id="2">20,000 PINS - $35</option>
     <option value="75" id="3">30,000 PINS - $75</option>
     <option value="140" id="4">50,000 PINS - $140</option>
     </select>
```

with this:

```
<select id="item_name" name="item_name" style="width:256px; height:32px;"></select>
<input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value=""/>
<script>
  var items = [
      { name: "10,000 PINS", amount: 18 },
      { name: "20,000 PINS", amount: 35 },
      { name: "30,000 PINS", amount: 75 },
      { name: "50,000 PINS", amount: 140 }
  ];
  var itemNameElement = document.getElementById("item_name");

  itemNameElement.onchange = (function(){
      var amount = items[this.selectedIndex].amount;
      document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
  }).bind(itemNameElement);

  document.getElementById("amount").value = items[0].amount;
  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
      var item = document.createElement("option");
      item.value = items[i].name;
      item.text = items[i].name+" - $"+items[i].amount;

      itemNameElement.add(item);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much fo helping me out..
The code worked wonders :-)

Just one more thing.. can you please clarify " I think it would be unethical not make sure you understand something first".
I shall be thankful to you for this.

Comment: It seems to me, you are using the value of 'amount' that you get from this form for paypal purchase. If this is a form that customers use, you shouldn't have 'amount' on the form. This is like a customer telling you what they want AND how much they are going to pay you. Someone could send the information 'item_name= 50,000 PINS, amount: 1'. Just make sure that when you are handling the information from this form, you make sure that the value of 'amount' is what it should be for the 'item_name'.

Comment: I appreciate your concern @Xion Dark. But i have done what you have suggested.
thanks again :-)